# ImportError: cannot import name 'delf_config_pb2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, image-recognition

Installed DELF through Ubuntu terminal on a Google Cloud instance for image recognition using these instructions: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/INSTALL_INSTRUCTIONS.md

The last step to test installation says "should just return without complaints. This indicates that the DELF package is loaded successfully." I run that but it gives me

```
"/home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives."
```

So, not sure if this means DELF was installed successfully or not.

Then, when trying the example to run delf (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/EXTRACTION_MATCHING.md) when I run

```
python extract_features.py \
  --config_path delf_config_example.pbtxt \
  --list_images_path list_images.txt \
  --output_dir data/oxford5k_features
```

it returns the error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_features.py", line 34, in <module>
    from delf import delf_config_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'delf_config_pb2'"
```

So it is importing delf, but not 'delf_config_pb2'.

It worked when I followed the exact same instructions on my local ubuntu, but is failing on google cloud ubuntu instance.

Also, when I stop the instance and then restart it, it says delf is not installed and fails to even import delf; so I have to follow the installation instructions again each time.

Answer (score 0):

Protoc complier generates `delf_config_pb2` file

so make sure that you installed it correctly

```
wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
echo 'export PATH=/path/to/protoc/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

or check out here how to install protoc compiler

[http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html][1]

check that protoc complier is installed.

type `protoc` on terminal and see if the command works.

After installing protoc, type this command

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/delf/
protoc delf/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

and you can add the path into .bashrc file in google cloud not to reinstall delf.

In google cloud. (check the location of the tensorflow model folder you've installed)

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:tensorflow/models/research' >> ~/.bashrc
```